# Sketching complex curves in the w- plane for using Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand what is being discussed in the page-386 of Tristan Needham's Visual Complex Analysis Book:
[image]

Figures 7:

[image]

Figure 8:

[image]

I'm having a hard time understanding what he is talking about the turning angle idea. He says that if the angle of $w$ i.e: point on the output curve changes by $t_i$ , then turning angle also increases by $t_i$.. but what does it mean?

What even is $\tilde{\phi}$? Can someone explain the whole idea of what Tristan Needham is trying to convey in simple words? I'm really confused as to how to approximate the turning of the curve in output plane from looking at input plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needham is attempting to construct a geometric interpretation of the Riemann Sum in the complex plane. For each piece of the Riemann Sum in $\mathbb{R^2}$, he proposes an analogous geometric description in $\mathbb{C}$. $$A=\sum_{i}^{n}f(x_{i})\Delta_{i}$$ Now what happens instead when we have $$A=\sum_{i}^{n}f(z_{i})\Delta_{i}$$
In the previous pages, he discussed the midpoint Riemann Sum tending to a limiting value, in this case, $$\int_{K}f(z)dz$$ and a justification for it. $$f(z)=w$$ Therefore, the curve in the w-plane is a mapping of the curve in the z-plane. Therefore if we take the Riemann sum along the path in the z-plane, we have $$A=\sum_{i}^{n}w_{i}\Delta_{i}$$ where $\Delta_{i}$ are partitions along the path and $w_{i}$ are the midpoints on the path. There should be one more diagram after this that gives a representation of what the ϕ~  are. The key point is that when you multiply two complex numbers, you add their arguments one's magnitude is scaled by the other. Therefore the Riemann Sum in the complex plane is the sum of the vectors/complex numbers $w_{i}\Delta_{i}$ added tail to head. Therefore when the argument of $w_{i}$ rotates by a factor, the argument of $w_{i}\Delta_{i}$ rotates by that same factor. Also, note that in the original curve not all the $\phi_{i}$ are positive.
As an illustration of this, in the next diagram in the book, note that the longest arrow is first, corresponding to the fact that all the $\Delta_{i}$ are the same and that $f(a)$ is the farthest away from the origin and that they're also adding the arguments in the manner I described earlier.

Comment: I understood this part but I don't get how this explains how to sketch out curves using the turning angle method

Comment: Turning angle method: Calculate the first $ \Delta_{1} $ using the method described earlier, then $ arg(w_{2})= \alpha + \tau_{1} $ and $ arg(\Delta_{2})=\beta+\phi_{1}$.Therefore, 
 when you multiply the two complex numbers, we get $arg(\Delta_{2}w_{2}) =\alpha + \tau_{1} + \beta+\phi_{1}$ .However, it would be cumbersome to do this each time, so we recognize we only want how much the new vector turns from the old vector and subtract $\alpha + \beta$ and iterate this process, instead focusing on how much the vecor turns.